# How to view stored properties data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

We have data in Elasticsearch which is mapped using `_source` and `properties` in the mapping configuration.
Now we want to see what's in the `properties` fields but can't seem to find a way to make em shown in the `{index}/doc/{docid}` output.
The data is stored because when we query on a field from a property it shows the correct result.
Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docvalue_fields` solves it. When fields aren't marked as `store: true` in the mapping they aren't showing up when using `fields`,`stored_fields` options. The how's and why's are still unclear to me.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "productNumber": "HQ000003784"
        }
    },
    "docvalue_fields": [
        "productNumber"
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": []
}
```